# Google Sheets keep data together when a referenced sheet is sorted

Tags: google-sheets

I have 2 sheets on my google sheet. Sheet 2 references Sheet 1 for it's first 3 columns. I did this with an arrayformula(theSheetName_Columns).
The issue is when I add data to the other columns in sheet 2 how do I keep it with the same data in that row when sheet 1 is sorted.

For example in sheet 2 row 192 might say John 465
But then when sheet 1 is sorted the 465 might be with Bill when I need it to stay with John.

Any help would be appreciated on fixing this! Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]! Take the site [Tour] and review [ask]. Then [Edit] the question to include sample data and your expected result.  Convert copied cells/tables from Sheets to [proper markdown format](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/editing-help#tables). Tools like the [Markdown Table Generator](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables) can make this easier.  Include relevant formulas describing what did/didn't work and any errors you encountered.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your intention is to manually add data side-by-side with formula results. That exposes you to the risk of rows getting misaligned.

One way to avoid the issue would be to insert the new column to the existing data table instead of adding it next to formula results. Alternatively, use `vlookup()` to look up the data from yet another table by some unique key you have in all the tables.

See this thorough treatment of the [row misalignment issue](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/95901649).